# gorm invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm new at golang and gorm framework.

Here is my code that I used gorm to fetch database.

**db.go**

```
package db

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/teamhide/hfive_go/users"
    "log"
)

const (
    DbHost     = "localhost"
    DbPort     = "5432"
    DbUser     = "1"
    DbPassword = "1"
    DbName     = "1"
)

var db *gorm.DB
var err error

func Init() {
    db, err = gorm.Open(
        "postgres",
        fmt.Sprintf(
            "host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s sslmode=disable",
            DbHost,
            DbPort,
            DbUser,
            DbName,
            DbPassword,
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&users.User{})
    defer db.Close()
}

func GetDB() *gorm.DB {
    return db
}
```

**users/usecase.go**

```
package users

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/teamhide/gin_boilerplate/db"
)

type UserUsecase interface {
    RegisterUserUsecase(email, password1, password2 string) (bool, error)
}

func RegisterUserUsecase(email, password1, password2 string) (bool, error) {
    db := db.GetDB()
    fmt.Println(db)
    return true, nil
}
```

In usecase, as you know that I just printed db variable to check it has proper db data.

But when I execute it, it throw errors.

```
...
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
...
/Users/hide/go/src/github.com/teamhide/hfive_go/users/controllers.go:18 (0x15b3301)
        UserController.RegisterDefaultUser: uc.RegisterUserUsecase(form.Email, form.Password1, 
form.Password2)
...
```

Is there any problem with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace refers to the file `controllers.go:18`, which you didn't include here.

The `db.go` has an issue in the `Init()` function. You're closing the connection to the database once the function completes. Also, it seems that you're misunderstanding the behavior of `defer` keyword as you're using it at the end of the function.

Comment: You're right. Anyway, where should I close db connection? Is it unnecessary?

Comment: It is a good practice to close connections. Here, it seems that you want to close the connection when the app exits. The solution here would be to wire a connection in the application entry point and defer closing the connection.